# SPARQL Update in OWLAPI

Tags: sparql, owl, owl-api

how can I run [SPARQL Updates](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/) in OWLAPI 3? 
 which SPARQL Engine/API will I need?

Pellet is suggesting [a way](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/faq/owlapi-sparql/) to perform SPARQL Queries, but it is not for triple patterns.

The updates I will be using are as simple as:

```
PREFIX wine: <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#>
INSERT DATA { 
    wine:MountadamRiesling wine:hasBody "Lite" . 
}
```

Comment: SPARQL is based on RDF.  OWL can be serialized in RDF, but it doesn't have to be serialized in RDF.  You'll need to store your model in RDF and then any SPARQL engine should be able to process it.

Comment: There is no support for SPARQL in OWLAPI 3 or 4, currently. A possible workaround is to use a library like Jena to update a RDF file and then parse it as an OWL ontology with OWL API. However, if you plan to query the results with SPARQL, it can all be done without OWL API. What role is the OWL API serving in your application?

Answer (score 0):

The OWL APi does not support SPARQL.
Apache Jena supports SPARQL and SPARQL updates as well (it is the reference implementation for them)
I'd recommend you to start with their tutorials:
https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql.html

Answer (score 0):

Now there is [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/wiki/Examples#ex8) which is an OWL-API impl over Apache Jena.